# SUM Group BY with JOIN SQL Wrong Output

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables; the output is not as expected, when I try `group` with `join`.

Here are the tables:

**table1**
[image: table1]

**table2**
[image: table2]

Here is the code:

```
SELECT *, SUM(total_jual) AS totaljual, SUM(total_beli) AS totalbeli 
FROM penjualan 
JOIN pembelian ON penjualan.tgl_penjualan = pembelian.tgl_pembelian 
GROUP BY penjualan.tgl_penjualan
```

I want the this output: `**2017-08-16** **4404000** **18051000**`
How to achieve this ?

Comment: It's meaningless to include "*" in an aggregating query. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `SELECT * GROUP BY` is invalid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining you get one line for each permutation i.e. one line for each combination of where the join condition matches. This leads to four lines in your example where each value is duplicated. Try the select without the GROUP BY and you will see. In order to get the correct sum you need to join by an aggregated result from the second table:

```
SELECT penjualan.tgl_penjualan, 
       SUM(total_jual) AS totaljual, 
       max(b.total_beli) AS totalbeli 
FROM penjualan 
JOIN (SELECT tgl_pembelian, sum(total_beli) AS total_beli FROM pembelian
      GROUP BY tgl_pembelian) AS b 
  ON penjualan.tgl_penjualan = b.tgl_pembelian 
GROUP BY penjualan.tgl_penjualan;
```

Appologies for any syntax error. I have not tested the sql.

Comment: You are right, it should be max(b.total_beli) in the outer statement. I made an edit. min(b.total_beli) will give the same result since there is only one line.

Comment: Why 2017-07-26, 2017-07-31 and etc no output? @stenix

Comment: Because I use an inner join. If you want output for all dates that exist in the penjualan table, you need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of the default JOIN that will only show dates that exist in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT penjualan.tgl_penjualan, SUM(total_jual) AS totaljual, SUM(total_beli) AS totalbeli 
FROM penjualan JOIN pembelian ON penjualan.tgl_penjualan = pembelian.tgl_pembelian 
GROUP BY penjualan.tgl_penjualan;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT top 1 penjualan.tgl_penjualan,SUM(total_jual) AS totaljual,b.total_beli AS totalbeli 
FROM penjualan 
INNER JOIN (SELECT tgl_pembelian, sum(total_beli) AS total_beli 
            FROM pembelianGROUP BY tgl_pembelian) AS b 
ON penjualan.tgl_penjualan = b.tgl_pembelian 
GROUP BY penjualan.tgl_penjualan,b.total_beli;
```

Comment: wrong output, I want the output 2017-08-16 4404000 18051000

Comment: the output 2017-08-16 8808000 36102000

Comment: Can you provide some information with this code? Why does this work and the original doesn't?

Comment: Its because the condition given while joining table is given wrong...date in the first table is occurring twice in the second table..so the output will be double the original value..

Comment: Why 2017-07-26, 2017-07-31 and etc no output? @Nithin

Comment: u said u want this as output right : **2017-08-16** **4404000** **18051000**